# Adding Clickable Button on Leaflet Map

Tags: leaflet, javascript, css

I am trying to add a clickable button on Leaflet map. Right now using this:

```
<ion-content padding scrollbar-y-auto>   
  <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
  <div class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-right">
    <button ion-button class="button-action" (click)="Action()"  block>Action!>/button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

CSS:

```
page-map {
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Minecraft';
    src: url('../assets/Minecraft.ttf')
    }   
    .button-action{
      height: 40px;
      width: 200px;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      background: url('https://i.hizliresim.com/QpVGbg.png') no-repeat;
      font-family: Minecraft;
      line-height: 26px;
      padding-top: 6px;
  }   
  .button-action:hover{
      background: url('https://i.hizliresim.com/a1zraR.png') no-repeat;
  }    
}
```

This is what I got:

[image]

I can't click the button it's like a picture also hover option is not working too.

`class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-right">` killing the button, or somehow button goes behind map so I can't click

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [L.EasyButton](https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton)? It's quick and easy, although the buttons can contain only icons out of the box. There's plenty of useful examples and demos on site.

If that doesn't suit your needs, you'll have to extend Leaflets [L.control class](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#control). Let me know and I'll try to work up an example using L.Control

Comment: because im using ionic 3 using external js is not my preferable option :/

Comment: If you put the button outside the map div, it should work, inside/on the map you will need a custom control for the button.

Comment: yea outside map div it works but how to make it on map not just below it

Comment: `L.easyButton` looks like a good choice but it hasn't been updated in over 4y.  It didn't work for me like the examples would indicate (created button didn't look anything like a normal Leaflet button).  Is it still relevant?

Answer (score 4):

I have tried to reproduce a working version, although I have not included the ionic framework.  I see a couple of problems with your code prior to bringing that library into the mix.

First off, you cannot nest vanilla CSS like you are currently doing.  You have to use less or sass in order to have nested CSS.  That being said, I removed the nesting and got the on hover to work.  Here is the code I used,

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .button-action{
        height: 40px;
        width: 200px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        background: url('https://i.hizliresim.com/QpVGbg.png') no-repeat;
        font-family: Minecraft;
        line-height: 26px;
        padding-top: 6px;
    }

    .button-action:hover{
        background: url('https://i.hizliresim.com/a1zraR.png') no-repeat;
    }

    </style>
    <script>
        function Action() {
            alert('HELLO');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
    <div class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-right">
        <button ion-button class="button-action" onclick="Action()"  block>Action!</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

You should be able to add the @font-face as well within the style block, although I did not have the files locally on my computer, so you will have to try adding that yourself.  Essentially just remove the higher level wrapper

```
page-map {}
```

The css should then be functioning properly.

In regards to the click action, you should be using

```
onclick="Action()"
```

instead of

```
click="Action()"
```

If the element is hidden behind some background layer, you can use z-index to move it to the foreground, but you need to use a position other than static, as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191803/why-does-z-index-not-work

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `z-index: 5;` in your CSS.

Comment: thanks for the answer but it didnt work

Comment: z index in leaflet are kinda high. control panels are at 800, try that or higher